# Formula for sequence of 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 and so on.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to figure out a formula for the sequence: $0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, ...$ and so on . It is not geometric and it is not arithmetic, I tried to apply these formulas, but of them are failing leading me to believe it is sum of arithmetic and geometric, can this be possible? How to get the formula for the sequence?

Comment: How about $x_{n}=\lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}_{0}$?

Comment: Are you looking for the sum formula or the term formula?

Comment: sum of formula.

Comment: [Here's a link to the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A046155).

Comment: If you want the sum of the terms, you should edit your question to say that.  Asking a clear question is a good way to solving the problem.

Comment: Using the interpolating polynomial $$\frac{523x^{13}}{6227020800}-\frac{61x^{12}}{7484400}+\frac{15457x^{11}}{43545600}-\frac{99751x^{10}}{10886400}+\frac{2263841x^9}{14515200}-\frac{1671559x^8}{907200}+\frac{674449411x^7}{43545600}-\frac{1017062803x^6}{10886400}+\frac{4383116309x^5}{10886400}-\frac{6632218813x^4}{5443200}+\frac{12488142437x^3}{4989600}-\frac{5459091523x^2}{1663200}+\frac{79963813x}{32760}-766,$$ the next number is $42$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the sum up to term $n$, the number of triplets up to term $n$ is $\lfloor \frac {n-1}3 \rfloor$, so multiply the sum of the numbers up to that by $3$.  Then add the last one or two numbers, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can define this sequence Piecewise:

> $  a_{n + 1} = \begin{cases} 
>       1 & a_n = 0 \\
>       a_n & n \text{ is not multiple of 3} \\
>       a_n + 1 & n \text{ is a multiple of 3} 
>    \end{cases}
>  \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and you start the sequence with } a_0=0$

Answer (score 0):

A continuous version is
$$\frac n3 -\frac2{3\sqrt3}\sin\frac{2\pi n}3$$